# why is python trying to open its help in my program?

Tags: python, input

So i am working on a command line program in python, and one of my commands is "help", which prints info on the various commands as you would expect. However, when i enter "help" using the input() method, and then split it, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 385, in <module>
    cmd(userinput)
  File ..., line 292, in cmd
    parts = line.split(' ', 1)
AttributeError: '_Helper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

and when i have it print what user just entered i get

```
Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
```

Why on earth is python executing its shell help inside of my program?

for reference, the relevant bits of code are

```
def cmd(line):
    print line
    parts = line.split(' ', 1)

 cmd(input(">"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `input` function (in Python 2.x) *ever*, use `raw_input` and parse the returned string. `input` will *eval* the string the user entered (same as `eval(raw_input('>'))`) and there is a global named "help", which is evaluated. Thus the behavior you see.

Python 3 has only `input` which acts like `raw_input` (does not eval), so on Python 3 you should use `input`.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's what `input()` in 2.x does: it tries to evaluate the string entered. Use `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. As others have pointed out, `input` on Python 2.x *evaluates* the input and returns the result.  Since `help` is a builtin python function, python returns the `help` function.
2. The `help` function is actually an instance of `site._Helper`.  `site._Helper_` overrides the default `__repr__` on object.  Now when print turns `help` into a string, `object.__str__` will be called, which will turn around and invoke `_Helper.__repr__`, which will print the help mesage.  That is why you see the python help message when you print it.

Of course, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.